# Hosting .NET Core as sub app of .NET app IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an existing ASP.NET app in IIS with domain: myapp.domain.com
I have a new .NET Core app I need to deploy.  Is it possible to publish this app under that same subdomain and not affect the existing app?  myapp.domain.com/newapp
IIS 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can simply add the output folder of the new app as a new application UNDER your current "Default Website". It will inherit Web.Config settings from the parent app, so be aware you may need to override these with a specific web.config for your new sub-app.

Also, as the other answer states, you may need to create a new Application Pool for your new app.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing @cklimowski's answer, keep in mind that you need to specify a seperate application pool to your .net core app.

Comment: Thank you.  I did create a separate app pool too.  Everything is working fine